# organizar condicionais para uma query SQL

Tags: php

Tenho a seguinte instrução SQL para fazer uma busca no banco de dados:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH(title,content,tag) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
```

porém existem alguns opções que podem ser ativadas, como **limitar** a quantidade de resultados, filtrar do **menor para o maior**, filtrar por **valor de coluna.**

A lógica que estou usando atualmente é algo como isso:

```
if($limit)
$query .= " LIMIT {$limit}";
```

para todos os valores opcionais.

existe alguma maneira mais eficiente de mudar o valor da `$query` quando se tem muitos "IFs"?

OBS:: Muitos desses filtros podem ser usados ao mesmo tempo.

Comment: Não, não existe. Podes é usar uma biblioteca de interação com a base de dados.